# Titanium, Forward and Rewind with createaudioPlayer

Tags: ios, slider, titanium, duration, audio-player

I've created an audioPlayer and a slider to work together: Slider moves while the music plays. It does. Now I want to be able to forward and rewind with the slider. It doesn't work, I guess it is because it is a streaming component. But wouldn't it at least be able to rewind since that is already buffered content? Lets say I put the song length in my array. Wouldn't be possible to make a function that controls where in the song I am?

Well it doesn't work. Any suggestions? This works perfect with createSound.

```
slider.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
audioPlayer.pause(); 
});

slider.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
audioPlayer.progress = slider.value;
audioPlayer.play(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i solved the problem:

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/143856/custom-forward-and-rewind-with-slider-on-createvideoplayer#comment-144979